# Angular building both es5 and es2018 targets

Tags: angular

Platform: Angular CLI 11.0.3. Angular 11.0.3. Mac OS.

I have a project that has been upgraded over many years and now uses Angular 11.0.3. When I do a build it produces both es5 and es2018 output.

[image]

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this.

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

It looks like `index.html` is using both sets of scripts.

```html
<script src="runtime-es2018.681bd8a4edb177c86959.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.681bd8a4edb177c86959.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.b516c02b9f8eaec4ec49.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2018.ba78947c8b103ff9cbd4.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es2018.2470cef227bbd6721f1b.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.2470cef227bbd6721f1b.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

Is this really necessary? Do I need both builds? If not how do I configure the system to get just one of the builds?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the `.browserslistrc` file was missing in my project. Somehow various upgrades done to this project did not migrate the browser list file correctly. I created a brand new project and simply copied the `.browserslistrc` file over. Now Angular is building only one set of scripts.